# List NPM workspaces similar to lerna ls

Tags: npm, npm-workspaces

I'm looking for an NPM command similar to `lerna ls` that would print out all workspaces.

For example, let's say I have `package1` and `package2` in a `packages` sub-directory and my package.json looks like this:

```
"workspaces": [
 "./packages/*"
]
```

I would like to get a list of NPM 7 workspaces. For the example I would expect:

- packages/package1
- packages/package2

I was hoping `npm ls -p --depth 0` would do this, but unfortunately it's printing out other dependencies as well.

I guess I could use `npm ls -json` and parse out the top level dependencies. However, I'm hoping there's a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a new way in `npm@8`:

```
npm query .workspace | jq -r '.[].location'
```

Returns the expected result:

```
packages/package1
packages/package2
```

Still requires `jq`, but slightly cleaner than before.

Comment: Note: the `query` command does not exist in the npm bundled with Node.js v16

Answer (score 2):

So for now I'm using JQ for this.

Example:
`npm ls --production --depth 1 -json | jq -r '.dependencies[].resolved'`

For my example this results in:

```
file:../../packages/package1
file:../../packages/package2
```

I don't know why it adds `../../` in front of it. So to further improve this: `npm ls --production --depth 1 -json | jq -r '.dependencies[].resolved[11:]'` returns the expected result:

```
packages/package1
packages/package2
```

I've also submitted a feature request here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4086

Comment: the `../../` is because it's the path that the symlink uses from the `node_modules/@my-scope` folder. If you have a non-scoped package in your workspace, it would just be a single `../`

Comment: npm ls --production --depth 1 -json | jq -r '.dependencies[].resolved' | sed 's/file:\.\.\///'

Comment: @t33n this persons seds

Answer (score 2):

This should work on npm version >= 8

```
npm ls -ws
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is looking for a pure NodeJS-npm solution:

```
npm exec -ws -c 'node -e "console.log(require(\"./package.json\").name)"'
```

Comment: This would actually be really really great, but it's awfully slow.

Answer (score -1):

here is a bash version:

```
npm pkg get name -ws | grep -o '"@[_0-9a-z-]*/[_0-9a-z-]*":' | tr -d "'\":"
```

[screenshot of work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnBZL.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).